# fullcitebib is alphabetizing my entries!! & I do not want it to?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have been using \fullcitebib for years for my weekly lists of readings for my graduate seminars. My PROBLEM is that it has started alphabetizing my entries rather than listing them the way I want them. For example, I give it:

```
\fullcitebib{holding92prf,lane11niip, charness12niip}
```

because I want:

Holding, D. H. (1992). Theories of chess skill. Psychological Research-Psychologische Forschung, 54(1), 10–16.

Lane, P. C. R. & Gobet, F. (2011). Perception in chess and beyond: Commentary on Linhares and Freitas (2010). New Ideas in Psychology, 29(2), 156–161.

Charness, N. (2012). Patterns of theorizing about chess skill: Commentary on Linhares and Freitas (2010) and Lane and Gobet (2011). New Ideas in Psychology, 30(3), 322–324.

but I am getting

Charness, N. (2012). Patterns of theorizing about chess skill: Commentary on Linhares and Freitas (2010) and Lane and Gobet (2011). New Ideas in Psychology, 30(3), 322–324.

Holding, D. H. (1992). Theories of chess skill. Psychological Research-Psychologische Forschung, 54(1), 10–16.

Lane, P. C. R. & Gobet, F. (2011). Perception in chess and beyond: Commentary on Linhares and Freitas (2010). New Ideas in Psychology, 29(2), 156–161.

This seems crazy. I have checked pdfs of my old syllabi to confirm that I was not hallucinating. But when I rerun LaTeX for those, the new files have alphabetized my fullcitbib listings.

Comment: Perhaps the defaults of `biblatex-apa` (which I'm guessing your are using) have changed. Try `\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=false]{biblatex}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting citations was explicitly enabled in `biblatex-apa` in commit [cb2dccd](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/commit/cb2dccdd10c39b91e879238cbb724539d6f4554a) on 1 March 2018.

Interestingly, in § 4.1 the manual states:

> Please note that APA style does not have multiple citation lists
>   sorted—they appear in the order cited. Since \fullcitebib is a
>   citation command, the citations will not be sorted which might appear
>   odd since this ‘citation’ style looks like a references section
>   excerpt.

But presumably this is out of date. I submitted a bug report at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/65

You have two options.

You can globally turn off sorting of citations by passing `sortcites=false` to `biblatex`. i.e., `\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=false]{biblatex}`. But this might not be desirable if normal citations are still to be sorted.

Alternatively, you can locally turn off sorting of citations as in the following MWE.

Here I create a new macro `\disablesortcites` and call it in `\AtNextCite` before the calling `\fullcitebib`. Other cite commands in the document are unaffected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{holding92prf,
  author = {Holding, Dennis H.},
  date = {1992},
  title = {Theories of Chess Skill},
  journaltitle = {Psychological Research-Psychologische Forschung},
  volume = {54},
  number = {1},
  pages = {10-16}
}
@article{lane11niip,
  author = {Lane, Peter C. R. and Gobet, Fernand},
  date = {2011},
  title = {Perception in Chess and Beyond},
  subtitle = {Commentary on {Linhares} and {Freitas} \mkbibparens{2010}},
  journaltitle = {New Ideas in Psychology},
  volume = {29},
  number = {2},
  pages = {156-161}
}
@article{charness12niip,
  author = {Charness, Neil},
  date = {2012},
  title = {Patterns of Theorizing About Chess Skill},
  subtitle = {Commentary on {Linhares} and {Freitas} \mkbibparens{2010} and {Lane} and {Gobet} \mkbibparens{2011}},
  journaltitle = {New Ideas in Psychology},
  volume = {30},
  number = {3},
  pages = {322-324}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\disablesortcites}{%
  \boolfalse{sortcites}%
  \let\blx@thecitesort\blx@citenosort
  \let\blx@thenotecheck\relax}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\cite{holding92prf, lane11niip, charness12niip}

\AtNextCite{\disablesortcites}
\fullcitebib{holding92prf, lane11niip, charness12niip}

\cite{holding92prf, lane11niip, charness12niip}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: David's first suggestion worked perfectly -- I implemented it in my current document which has 109 citations listed non-alphabetically in various subsections throughout. I also implemented it in my LaTeX files for the syllabus from Spring 2017. Both documents now have the "by week" readings (using fullcitebib listed in the order I placed them, rather than alphabetically. Thanks David!